# When using WebProxy, what does BypassOnLocal really mean/do?

Tags: c#

When setting up a new WebProxy instance, you can indicate whether it is a BypassOnLocal. What does this actually do? And what would I typically want to keep it as?

`WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(uri, BypassOnLocal: true);`

Comment: This doesnt seem much like a SO question.  More generic understanding of proxys and settings.. BypassOnLocal does that for local stuff dont go through the proxy..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Large organization, all network request goes through the proxy server. So if you are developing an enterprise application using c# and wanted to handle this proxy server then I would recommend using this and mostly we don't want proxy server to handle the request for resources available in the same PC so we can bypass the proxy server for all local requests.

Hope this helps.